# How do I solve a differential equation with a power series if $x_0 = 1$ and the equation has coefficients of the second power

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

That is, the power series will have $(x-1)^n$ but one of the coefficients in the equation is $1+2x-x^2$. I could deal with the $1$ and the $2x$ but how can I multiply the $x^2$ into the power series with $(x-1)^n$? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is incomplete

Comment: This sounds weird. Why don't you give us the actual problem and tell us what you are thinking about it and what you desire?